# How to have a line number in latex

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing, sections-paragraphs, overleaf

I am writing my thesis using overleaf. Sometimes I need to paste some paragraph from one chapter and paste it on another chapter of my thesis. By doing so, I find that the pasted paragraph has no line number. It is very important for me to have a line number. Hence, I do that manually which takes a time. That is, I come to the end of each line and press enter and do that for the whole paragraph.

My question is, is there a shortcut to do this task?

For example, here is my writing in overleaf editor. There is no line number for this paragraph. So, How can I add the line number after writing the paragraph?.

[image: This what I meant]

Please forgive me if I select the wrong tags. I really do not know what is the best tag for my question.

Comment: Your query sounds like it's related to Overleaf's built-in editor. Have you tried posting a query on Overleaf's help site?

Comment: I can have a line number only when I press `enter` after each sentence.

Comment: Overleaf's editor already has line numbers... do you mean you want line numbers to appear in your output PDF?

Comment: @LianTzeLim. Thanks for your comment. Yes, Overleaf's editor already has line numbers. However, If you write a long sentence then there will be no line number. So each time to start a new line with a line number you have to press `enter`. That is fine. However, sometimes, I write very long sentences or paste them from other sources. Then, I need to divide them into lines manually.

Comment: @LianTzeLim I have added a picture

Comment: That's how plain text editors work: only every "real" line (i.e. with an `enter`) counts as a line and receive a line number. Picture this: if you resize the source code panel, then the number of characters per line change, and you'll have different line numbers all over if every wrapped line are numbered.